# Azure Devops remove Domain User Group privileges

Tags: security, active-directory, azure-devops, devops

We have Azure DevOps 2019 installed in our internal network, but all of Domain users admins(Active Directory) have full access to our collections, How Can I revoke their access?

[image]

Comment: Check the `Project Collection Valid Users` group, who are the members?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk not they're not. members are our collection project valid users

Answer (score 0):

You can search the Domain Admins. If you find it, click to enter it, you will see the interface like below, then choose the Permissions Tab to set the permission. For example:

[image]

Comment: @Payam Khaninejad Has the problem been solved? If not,please feel free to tell use the problem.